# How to order a discrete variable in a scatterplot by a third grouping variable with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

I have the following simple data table (generated with `dput()`):

```
data <- structure(list(study = c("Brennan (2009)", "Farabee (2010)", 
                         "Fass (2008)", "Mills (2007)", "Fass (2008)", "Howard (2013)", 
                         "Latessa (2017)", "Lovins (2018)", "Lowenkamp (2015)", "Allan (2006)", 
                         "Endrass (2009)", "Looman (2006)", "Retterberg (2006)", "Sreenivasan (2007)"), 
               year = c(2009, 2010, 2008, 2007, 2008, 2013, 2017, 2018, 2015, 
                        2006, 2009, 2006, 2006, 2007), 
               tool = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
                                .Label = c("COMPAS", 
                                           "HCR-20", "LSI-R", "OASys", "ORAS", "PCRA", "Static-99"), class = "factor"), 
               auc = c(0.66, 0.7, 0.53, 0.72, 0.6, 0.72, 0.6, 0.66, 0.73, 
                       0.78, 0.76, 0.63, 0.74, 0.62)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -14L), .Names = c("study", 
                                              "year", "tool", "auc"), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
          ))
```

**Problem:**

I would like to present the data in a scatterplot with "study" on the y-axis and "auc" on the x-axis. I would also like to group the data by "tool" (i.e., show each tool in a different color). Although everything works fine, I am not able to order my discrete y-axis by the grouping variable "tool" (see example below).

**Example:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
###################

arrange(data, tool, study, year) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = auc, y = study)) + 
       geom_point(aes(color = tool), size = 4)
```

[image: Example plot]

As you can see, the order of each point is defined by "study". However, I would like to have the order defined by "tool" so that all points with the same color are underneath each other. I have read some stackoverflow posts about `reorder()`and `rev()`, but did not find them helpful for my particular problem as they did not order their data by a third grouping variable.

Any help will be much appreciated,

Matthias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With reorder:

```
data %>% mutate(study=reorder(study, as.numeric(tool))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = auc, y = study)) +  
  geom_point(aes(color = tool), size = 4)
```

Explanation: using `reorder` you convert the study to a factor, thus enforcing on ggplot a certain order. The order is given by `as.numeric(tool)`. We have to convert it to a numeric vector, because `tool` is not an ordered factor.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try `forcats::fct_reorder()`.

For example:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = auc, y = forcats::fct_reorder(study, as.numeric(tool)))) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = tool), size = 4)
```

n.b. faceting by tool may be more informative. e.g.

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = auc, y = forcats::fct_reorder(study, auc))) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  facet_wrap(~tool)
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing the same job as Jon above, but another way would be to do a factor of study names in the order given, and use that to order the plot:

```
levels <- data %>% 
  arrange(tool, study, year) %>% pull(study)

data %>% 
  mutate(study = factor(study, levels = unique(levels))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = auc, y = study)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = tool), size = 4)
```

Your `Fass (2008)` point becomes a bit tricky, combining two tools on the same line. Is this intended?

[image]

Comment: I would prefer it if Fass(2008) was showing the data points separately. But I guess, I can simply change the name to Fass (2008); COMPAS and Fass (2008); LSI-R which wouldn't be a big deal as many researchers in my field do the same.

Comment: good luck with last phases of that. The two reordering suggestions are certainly more straightforward than mine here.